# Как отобразить position: absolute элемент поверх родителя с прокруткой

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend

У меня в проекте есть div c `overflow-x: auto`, ограниченный по высоте (например 500px). Когда высота div по мере роста количества элементов внутри него становится более 500px, появляется вертикальный скролл - всё ок, так и нужно.

Проблема заключается в том, что в нижней части этого `div` есть кастомные `combobox`, у которых `div` со списком опций c `position: absolute` начинают растягивать родительский `div` по высоте и из-за этого возникает прокрутка, а мне нужно, чтобы эти `div` с опциями показывались поверх родителя.

Пример примитивный, показывающий, что происходит: https://codepen.io/v-mokrushin/pen/qBQGJdj

**Покажу ещё на скриншотах.**

**Нежелательное поведение:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Желательное поведение (добился отключением прокрутки, но она нужна в любом случае):**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему.

Comment: никак. `overflow` вы задали такой, который заставляет div скроллиться, если контент превышает его габариты. и `position` контента на это не влияет. все сайты, где подобная необходимость встречается, рендерят выпадающую часть кастомного комбобокса ВНЕ скроллируемого контейнера и позиционируют его в нужное место относительно основной части скриптом.